# Non linear differential equation plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear, modeling

Consider the following paper:

https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0096300306007715?token=2B98E3B12F1E623C99A0787996469AF36E8EF230F6ED5289EAFB60B64CE79A6ACCF74B946A34F3370C65D4FC99018648&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210825115609

From my understanding figure 2(on page 5) is a graph of $s(t), i(t)$ and $r(t)$ by the function in the appendix(page 6) for case 1.

However, when I try plotting this function, I get the wrong out output, why?

```
Plot[{ 1 - 
   0.36*t + (0.72*10^-1)*t^2 - (0.96*10^-2)*t^3 + (0.96*10^-3)*
    t^4 - (0.768*10^-4)*t^5 + (0.5688888892*10^-6)*t^6, 
  0.36*t - (0.72*10^-1)*t^2 + (0.96*10^-2)*t^3 - (0.96*10^-3)*
    t^4 + (0.768*10^-4)*t^5 - (0.512*10^-5)*t^6}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: The solutions in the Appendix are only approximate solutions, not exact;  and power-series approximations get worse as their arguments get larger.  Note that your graph is pretty good for smaller values of $t$ and only diverges at larger values.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it arises from confusion about the applicability of certain published results, and has nothing to do with using the Mathematica software correctly or incorrectly.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I meant, my plot isn't plotting what the paper plotted..

Comment: Presumably the paper is plotting that actual numerical solutions to the differential equations.  The Appendix gives power-series approximations to these solutions, not the actual functions (which I suspect can't be written in closed form.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert isn't that defeating the purpose of Adomian decomposition? surely they should be plotting their solutions from Adomian decomposition rather than "actual" numerical solutions? that's what I would've thought anyway.. I have the actual numerical solutions and they match their plots but this is strange since that's not our objective!

Comment: I'm not really familiar with that technique, to be honest, so I couldn't say.  But I'm confident that Mathematica is correctly plotting the polynomials provided in the Appendix.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert just to revisit, it states under 4. numerical results and discussion that: "In this section, we monitor the effect of vaccination on the dynamics of a childhood disease described by the SIR model Eqs.(5)–(7) using Adomian decomposition technique." so this is why i was confused..